# How to know video input height and use it inside ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, video-encoding

I want to compile videos with ffmpeg using -crf rate control mode. 
However i want to use different crf value for different resolution videos.

e.g. for 320x240 videos i want to use -crf 23 and for 640x480 videos I want to use -crf 26.

I tried to use "if" function `-crf "'if(lte(ih,240),1,51)'"` combined with input height constant `ih`, but it seems to me that you can only use `ih` constant inside videofilters (`-vf`) because I get `Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'ih,240),1,51)'`-error when compiling. Otherwise the function is working great.

Is there a way to use the `ih` constant somewhere else than inside `-vf` or is there a easy way to know video files width. I'm doing batch processing so i can't do it manually.

Comment: Your batch will need an if-else statement where you read the height using ffprobe and then execute one command or the other based on the result.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I know how to use the ffprobe to get the height of the video, but how do I save the value? And how do I use the saved value in ffmpeg?

This ffprobe command gives me only the height value in numbers.
`ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height \
-of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 inputvideofile.mp4`

Comment: @Ode You can use variables in your preferred shell or scripting language. If you mention your OS and/or preferred language we may be able to provide an example command.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard  Our developer managed to to the exact thing you mentioned, so thank you! 

Only thing is I'm still wondering why you can't use `ih`, `iw` etc, values outside `-vf` parameter. It would make a lot of things easier.

Comment: Since you found a solution you can provide an answer to your own question which may help others.